# Shortcut to replace generic type with another generic type?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, generics, keyboard-shortcuts

Here is my code [image]

What happened was I copied and pasted my generic superclass's code for the remove method into my subclass. However in my subclass, I named my generic type Type, not E. Is there a shortcut that I can use in eclipse to replace all occurrences of generic type E with generic type Type? I saw search and replace in http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html but I don't want to replace every occurrence of the letter E, just the generic type.

Comment: Calling a type parameter `Type` is kind of confusing... But anyway, don't you have the option to rename the type parameter at the class level? IDEA can do this

Comment: I am eclipse, not Intellij

Comment: Still, this doesn't mean that Eclipse does not have this option, right? But as I don't use Eclipse I can't help any further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can still use the search and replace but with a regular expression (you need to tick the "Regular expressions" checkbox in the dialog). Try replacing:

```
(\W)E(\W)
```

with

```
\1Type\2
```

The regex matches the letter E surrounded by non-word characters (e.g. whitespace or angle brackets).